# Connecting 2 singly linked lists by using a dummy node

Tags: c, list, merge, linked-list

A little background info, we are doing this huge project and a part of it is about merging 2 singly linked lists.
The linked lists both have a different dummy node to their end and its next field is pointing to the node before, so that we have access to the tail of the list and be able to merge the 2 lists in O(1)
I print both my lists, then try to merge them, but when i print the merged list, i see 2 extra data that are adresses and I cant find out why.

```
List1 = 500,501,502,
List2 = 600,601,
List3 = 500,501,502,ADDRESS,ADRESS,600,601
```

The node has a *next field and an int id field. So dummynode *next shows to the last valid node of list1 and so does the dummynode of list2 respectively
Board[i].ptr and Board[k].ptr are the starting points of each list

and here is the code:

```
Board[i].dummynode->next->next = Board[k].ptr;
free(Board[i].dummynode);
Board[i].dummynode= Board[k].dummynode;
node * u = Board[i].ptr;

while(u!=Board[k].dummynode)
{
    printf("%d ",u->id);
    u = u->next;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `Board[i].dummynode->next` wasn't actually pointing at the tail of `Board[i]`.  Can you print `Board[i].dummynode->next->id` before you combine the two lists?

Comment: how do i make this best answer in the whole world? thanks mate! ive been looking in the wrong code the whole time!

Comment: No problem.  I'll make my comment an answer so you can resolve this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `Board[i].dummynode->next` wasn't actually pointing at the tail of `Board[i]`. Can you print `Board[i].dummynode->next->id` before you combine the two lists?

If my guess is right, then you will traverse from tail of i to the old i dummy node, then to whatever that was pointing at, and then to the head of k.

```
i0 -> i1 -> i2 -> i dummy -> random
k0 -> k1 -> k2 -> k dummy
```

becomes

```
i0 -> i1 -> i2 -> i dummy -> random -> k0 -> k1 -> k2 -> k dummy
```